# How gradle task deal with extension objects

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, android-gradle-plugin

## About Bintray-release plugin

I am using [bintray-release](https://github.com/novoda/bintray-release) to upload my library to maven.Its doc says how to use it:

> Use the publish closure to set the info of your package:

```
publish {
    userOrg = 'novoda'
    groupId = 'com.novoda'
    artifactId = 'bintray-release'
    publishVersion = '0.3.4'
    desc = 'Oh hi, this is a nice description for a project, right?'
    website = 'https://github.com/novoda/bintray-release'
}
```

> Finally, use the task `bintrayUpload` to publish

```
 $ ./gradlew clean build bintrayUpload -PbintrayUser=BINTRAY_USERNAME -PbintrayKey=BINTRAY_KEY -PdryRun=false
```

## In my case

Then I define my `publish` closure:

```
publish {
    groupId = 'com.uniquestudio'
    artifactId = 'parsingplayer'
    publishVersion = '2.0.6'
    website = 'https://github.com/TedaLIEz/ParsingPlayer'
    Properties properties = new Properties()
    InputStream inputStream = project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream() ;
    properties.load( inputStream )
    bintrayUser = properties.getProperty('bintrayUser')
    bintrayKey = properties.getProperty('bintrayKey')
}
```

As you can see,out of safety I put `bintrayUser` and `bintrayKey` into `local.properties`.

## My Question

### First

I know I can put `bintrayUser` and `bintrayKey` in `loacal.properties` and `gradle.properties`.Is there any other way to store private data while I don't think is't suitable to store private data within current project ?

### Second

Everything is ok but when I push my project to CI.I get error:

> /home/travis/build/TedaLIEz/ParsingPlayer/local.properties (No such file or directory)

So I want to know How gradle task deal with extension objects,in my case,`publish` object.Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I have to tell you that it is not recommended to ask two questions at once via StackOverflow, mainly because it may be hard to choose a correct answer, if two answers help you with the different questions you asked.

Anyhow, I'll try to answer both of your questions:

#### First

To use an additional properties file (`local.properties` in your case) is not a Gradle approach. It is in fact pure Java. You should only read properties on your own in very rare cases and **never** in a build script. If you really need an additional properties file, develop a Gradle plugin, which handles the file access.

Gradle automatically reads the `gradle.properties` file, but not only in the project directory, but also in the user-specific gradle home directory (e.g. `C:\Users\*<User>*\.gradle`). This is helpful to define private data, which won't find its way into version control, even if you forget to ignore the files manually. The defined data will be accessible to any project.

#### Second

Well, I assume the file `local.properties` does not exist, because you did neither put it under version control nor let your CI add it automatically. Where should the login data come from?

The solution is simple. Just add the required data to the CI user gradle home directories (e.g. `/home/travis/.gradle`) `gradle.properties` file. This way, you can also simply add access right management, by entering the login data of a CI user. Local builds will be published by your local user account (if allowed), CI builds by the CI system.

#### Appendix

Your question includes the Gradle specific term 'extension', but, to be honest, it got nothing to do with your question. It is correct, that most configuration in Gradle is done via so-called extension objects, that are added to the `Project` object, but it is an internal term, you do not need to understand it to fix this problem.

#### Edit: Comment answer

Now I can understand your confusion. Gradle distinguishes between the *configuration phase* and the *execution phase*. Nearly everything in your build script is executed during the *configuration phase*, only task actions (what a task does, e.g. copying, deleting ...), `doFirst` and `doLast` closures (so basically tasks) are executed during *execution phase*. If you define the list of tasks to be executed (via command line), it only affects the *execution phase*, but your configuration code will be executed at every single build, even if only one independent task is executed afterwards.

To solve this problem, follow the solution in the **First** block and add your private data to the user-specific Gradle directory `gradle.properties` file. It will be added to the `project` object and therefor, it will be accessible from the build file. But, since the file (or the data) does not exist on your CI, accessing it directly will raise an error when building on the CI. You can use the `findProperty(propertyName)` method as a fail-safe way to access the property value. If the property does not exist, it returns `null` (in the *configuration phase*), so no error occurs, as long as you don not execute the `bintrayUpload` task (which is not your goal on the CI).

Comment: I don't think it has nothing to do with `extension`.Because I don't invoke `./gradlew bintrayUpload` int CI so the `publish` extension is automatically invoked then it does not find `loacl.properties`.

Comment: @cole: I finallly understood your problem and added an explanation to the answer.